# Switch CSS of a rich:datascroller

Tags: css, jsf, richfaces, facet, datascroller

I wanna switch the styles the datascroller uses to shows the selected page. Is it possible?

```
<f:facet name="footer">
    <a4j:form>        
        <rich:datascroller styleClass="wrap-paginacao" for="estabelecimentoGrid" boundaryControls="hide" stepControls="show"  fastControls="hide"  >
            <f:facet name="previous">
                <h:graphicImage value="/home/img/previous.png"/>
            </f:facet>

            <f:facet name="next">
                <h:graphicImage value="/home/img/next.png"/>
            </f:facet>
        </rich:datascroller>
    </a4j:form>  
</f:facet>
```

**UPDATE**

Default styles:

[image: Default]

Styles I want:

[image: What I Want]

Comment: “I wanna switch the way the datascroller shows the page selected” — could you elaborate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

override `.rf-ds-act` class of richfaces to whatever you want..

if this does not suffice you right click scroller component and click on inspect element using firebug you will get which css to override.